# ASP.NET + MVC 4 + IIS 7 + MSSQL slow response

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-mvc

I have recently deployed an ASP.NET MVC4 application to a IIS 7 server, but something is not quite right. I have a log-in action that access the user credentials stored in a MSSQL 2008 R2 server, and when this access takes place, the access time takes around 13 secs. This is very high for a simple credential look-up.

I have tested the same application on local IIS with the same data-set in a replicated MSSQL server and performance is normal. What could be the issue here?

Comment: On the same server, if you perform the query manually (outside the ASP.NET application), is the response time the same?

Comment: We've got the same problem. Windows server 2008R2, IIS7.5, .NET 4.0. MVC3 apps and normal ASP.NET apps work just fine. The problem comes when we run MVC4 WEB API centric app on the same server. Have you guys resolved the issue?